# A successful Git branching model: why shouldn't I use release branches as my master?

Tags: git, branch

This might be a stupid question, but I can't figure out why I can't use my release branches as my master? I like the idea of "a successful Git branching model"(http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), but I can see that when I merge release branches to master, it's likely that I need to resolve many conflicts. So why not just use the release branches as my master?

Thanks!

**EDIT**
Sorry I didn't make my question clear enough. What I was trying to say was, what is the difference between this Git branching model and checking out from my release branch to a new branch, and using it as my new master branch. Does it make a difference between merging my release branch to my original master and checking out a new master branch?

Comment: Conflicts? There are no changes on master, how can there be conflicts?

Comment: If you use the release branch as master, you probably risk to have the tip of your branch being in a intermediate state, where not everything is ready yet. Merging to master is more of a way to actually release the code.

Comment: @Choroba, ah, yes, you are right. I've edited my question, please help me : )

Answer (score 0):

How would you "use your release branches as `master`"?  I'm not sure what that's supposed to mean, really.  Let's look at what `master` is and how you might use it, and see if you can do those things with release branches...

So first of all, the merge into `master` shouldn't create a new state of the code (which seems to be your objection); so maybe you think it doesn't do anything.  But it does: it signals that this specific version is an actual release.  It is being deployed to production, shipped to clients, whatever.  Any old version that happens to be the tip of a release branch might not be production-ready.  Of course you could use some sort of tagging convention to get around that, but I think you'd find the solution less elegant.

Next, if I checkout `master` - a single, unchanging name - I should know that I have the most recent production release version.  If I'm just relying on release branches, I'd have to know what version I want, or check what versions exist to pick the most recent.  That might not be too convenient for automated deployment tooling.  I could use a moving tag, but that's something of an anti-pattern.  A tag is just a ref, and if I want a ref that moves, there's a solution for that: a branch.  And that's what `master` is.

When I'm on `master`, I can do things like

```
git log --first-parent
```

and see a release history, with releases (and, incidentally, also hot fixes) shown in the order they happened.  No scripting contortions, no risk that something shows up out of order (or doesn't show up) because someone broke a convention.

Part of the point of the GitFlow model - the reason it uses `--no-ff` and has special named long-lived branches - is that commit topology has documentary value beyond the collection of patches that added up to the current code version.

Comment: Thank you so much for your very patient answer! I rephrased my question and could you please help me with it? This is what I really want to ask : )